# Can someone please go through how this program works. Im new to java

Tags: java, binary, decimal, converters

Please explain how this converts decimal to binary:

```
import java.util.*;

public class decimalToBinaryTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int number;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a positive interger");
        number = in.nextInt();

        if (number < 0) {
            System.out.println("Not a positive interger");
        }

        else {
            System.out.print("Convert to binary is: ");
            System.out.print(binaryform(number) + ".");
        }
    }

    private static Object binaryform(int number) {

        int remainder;

        if (number <= 1) {
            System.out.print(number);
            return null;
        }

        remainder = number % 2;
        binaryform(number >> 1);
        System.out.print(remainder);
        {
            return " ";
        }
    }
}
```

I mainly don't get the bit in private static object. Or the return " ". I really don't see how it does but it works. If you enter 10 it displays: Convert to binary is: 1010.

Do I need the >> 1 or can it be *0.5

Comment: it is called Recursion. Read more:http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/23recursion/

Comment: It seems that code author didn't know that (s)he can use `return` without value if declared methods return type is `void` and decide to return anything like null or `" "`. Also this method works in recursive way. First it calculates reminder, then moves bits right one place, `(6) 0110>>1` results in `(3) 0011` which is kind of the same as dividing integer by 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two important moments in this code:

```
binaryform(number >> 1);
```

first: recursion. Call function from this function (foo() {foo();}
second: bitwise. >>1 - shift number for 1 bit, it's the same to devide by 2.

every recursion iteration, code devide number by 2 and print reminder AFTER recursion function works (from last to first). It's like:

```
{
  {
    {
      {
      print inner (fourth iteration
      }
    print before inner (third iteration)
    }
  print before before inner (second iteration)
  }
print outer (first iteration)
}
```

Comment: Please explain recursion and why the program has to shift the number by 1 bit.What do you mean by its the same to divide by 2?

Comment: Check this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation about shifting. 110 (6) shifted to 1 bit to right >>1 : 011 (3 = 6/2)

Comment: @tomjdog Do you only need explanation of this particular recursive method or also what recursion is?

Comment: @Phesmo I want both as im new to java

Comment: @tomjdog it's not a Java specific code. It's principal in math and algoritmic. I show you in answer this recursion in full form.

Comment: @tomjdog Recursion is not related only to Java. Basically to understand recursion you need to first understand recursion (even google used it as suggested term while searching for "recursion"). More at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion

Comment: @tomjdog every time binaryform function calls - it calculates ONLY ONE! bit of number. But in binaryformat you call binaryformat second time before print the result and in this second iteration you call it again and again. Your result prints not in one operator `System.out.print(remainder);`, it prints 4 times (one digit a time) in different depth of recursion.

Comment: It may help if someone explained what happens to the variable number through the whole program

Comment: @tomjdog after binaryform call in main function, number%2 - reminder (10%2 = 0) reminder saves in memory, but not print because of second call binaryformat(5) in the next line with shift (in the second iteration number is `5` (10>>1 = 10/2 = 5)). reminder in second iteration is 5%2 = 1 and saves in memory, call third iteration of binaryformat(2) with 5>>1 = 2, third reminder = 0 and again binaryformat(1). In this iteration works case: `if (number <= 1)` and print 1 and retun null. Program run next line after binaryformat call `System.out.print(remainder);` with third reminder 0, then 1 then 0

Comment: @BaBL86 as the >>1 just divides by two do I need the>> 1 or can I just do *0.5?

Comment: @tomjdog You can, but you need to be carefull with numeric types and rounds: `3*0.5 = 1.5`, `round(1.5) = 2` but `3>>1 = 1`.

Comment: @BaBL86 this may seem like a stupid question but after the private static Object binaryform why is there int number in brackets.  Is it relating to the variable number I made in the main part?

Comment: `System.out.print(binaryform(number) + ".");` you call binaryform at first time with `number` from your main code. But inside binaryform you work with a "copy" of this variable (in main code after printing binaryform you have a full `number` variable without changes). But in binaryform on every iteration you have a different copy of `number`